# How to make internal links work in Sphinx output (latexpdf)?

Tags: reference, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I insert links following this manual:

http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#ref-role

However, while the internal links work perfectly in the HTML output, they don't work in PDF. The text supposed to be the clickable link only become italics.

Here's my rst:

```
This is my :ref:`reference <file-table3>`.

.. _file-table3:

.. container:: centeredtextbody

    .. table:: There is my table
```

When I build the html (make html), everything is as expected. When I build the pdf through latex (make latexpdf), no links in my file (except for the TOC ones)

What am I doing wrong? I would like for the links to appear in both html and pdf output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured my problem.

My architecture was:

```
index.rst

    text

    ..include: File.rst


File.rst

    links stuff
```

The problem was, I think, that sphinx was parsing my rst document twice (once as a rst file, once as an included file). This caused apparently the links to become \emph in latex, for unknown reasons.

Changing File.rst to File.txt solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Probably completely irrelevant after so many years, but for the sake of completeness:

Running `pdflatex` twice seems to work. In the first pass, latex only realises there's something going on there, but it does not have enough information to complete the link. The second pass, using the auxiliary files created on the first one, does have enough information and the link is properly stablished.

It is common in Latex to need two or more passes to ensure that all links - specially bibliography links - are correctly linked, so I am not surprise that is also the case for Sphinx documentation.

Cheers!